# MLPPP_Bundle_load sharing

Tags: troubleshooting

I have configured one MLPPP bundle with 6 E1`s. One of them getting utilize more than 80% while other one are just only 5 or 10 % utilize. How can i overcome from such issue.

Comment: Sharing configs, debugging output and information about what you've tested may help here, without that it's just guessing.

Comment: When you say on is utilized more than 80%, is that inbound, outbound, or both?

Comment: Which vendor/software version are you using, it could be a factor as well.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Different devices and software/firmware use different load-balancing hashing algorithms, what equipment are you using and what load-balancing method are you using?

Based on the minimal information you have given, you might just have unequal load balancing. With MLPPP you should be effectively be doing per-packet load-balancing across all the member links but that isn't always the case. If your set-up is doing per-IP balancing for example, you might have a couple of larger flows balanced onto the first link, or it may be that you have many flows between the same set of IPs which again are over-favouring for example the fist link.

Also check that all the links are in the MLPPP bundle and that they are running at the same or very similar speeds (user configuration for example might state one link is 2Mbps and another 8Mbps, when they should be all the same).

The RFC lists various discriminator factors used to determine which member links belong to which MLPPP bundle. Ensure those factors (whatever you have configured) are matching up so that all the links are actually in the bundle.

Also do you have access to both ends of the bundle, is there any discrepancy between MLPPP end-points?